# No code coverage result during the integration of SonarQube with TFS

Tags: tfs, msbuild, sonarqube

I am connecting SonarQube 5.6 with TFS 2013, ultimate version, using MSBuild to analyze the code. During the build, getting an error regarding `No code coverage Results`. I enabled code coverage in the build definition. Please check the error and give some suggestion.

```
Error:
No code coverage results
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
 at SonarQube.TeamBuild.Integration.CoverageReportUrlProvider.GetCodeCoverageReportUrls(String tfsUri, String buildUri, ILogger logger)
 at SonarQube.TeamBuild.Integration.TfsLegacyCoverageReportProcessor.TryGetBinaryReportFile(AnalysisConfig config, TeamBuildSettings settings, ILogger logger, String& binaryFilePath)
 at SonarQube.TeamBuild.Integration.CoverageReportProcessorBase.ProcessCoverageReports()
 at SonarQube.TeamBuild.PostProcessor.CoverageReportProcessor.ProcessCoverageReports()
 at SonarQube.TeamBuild.PostProcessor.MSBuildPostProcessor.Execute(String[] args, AnalysisConfig config, TeamBuildSettings settings, ILogger logger)
 at SonarQube.TeamBuild.PostProcessor.Program.Main(String[] args)
 Exception Message: TF270015: 'MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe' returned an unexpected exit code. Expected '0'; actual '255'. See the build logs for more details. (type UnexpectedExitCodeException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Activities.Statements.Throw.Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
   at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
   at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
```

Comment: Do you have VS 2013 installed on your build agent machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error indicates couldn't find assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client'. Please install VS2013 on the build agent. Alternatively, you can install object model which can be downloaded from website below:

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3278bfa7-64a7-4a75-b0da-ec4ccb8d21b6

See the [documentation](https://github.com/SonarSource-VisualStudio/sonar-.net-documentation/blob/master/doc/analyze-from-tfs.md) for more information.

Comment: Yes, You guys right, I had a 2012. I installed 2013 with team explorer. It works fine but got second error about the ProjectInfo.xml file. Check it below: